# Using firebase .update within a .where (instead of .doc)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and am struggling a little bit.

Currently, I am trying to update an array within a user, within a document. However, I cannot match the user to current user using the unique ID, as each users unique ID is their username, and it may have changed since creation.

I figured the best way to match the documents user to the current user would be to use a .where().get() and then use an "update()" to update the array.

Now, this is where I am getting stuck. In the firebase documents, their [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) of using .update is attached to a .doc

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

//Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});
```

However, as I am using a .where, I assume I have to use references and snapshots. But, I am not quite sure how references work in this scenario and, with that, how to update properly.

Here is the code I have after a while of messing round, but no matter my variations i cannot figure it out. (essentially, I want to add a new project (in this case called "new project" to the users array of postedProjects.)

```
 db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', this.userInfo.user_id)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot)  {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

    doc.data().update({
      postedProjects: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("new project")
    })
  })
})
```

This gives me an error of ".update() is not a function".

Is anyone able to help me with my solution to show me *how* references should properly be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You can't update the data of `DocumentSnapshot` though, since that is the in-memory representation of the document data. Instead you need to get the `DocumentReference` and call `update` on that.

```
doc.ref.update({
  postedProjects: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("new project")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) in order to [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) a document.  Nothing else will work.

In your code, `doc` is a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` type object.  If you want the DocumentReference object that refers to the document from that snapshot, use its [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref) property.

```
doc.ref.update({
    postedProjects: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("new project")
})
```